# Sign a Pdf Document using EvoPdf

Tags: c#, pdf, signing, x509certificate2, evopdf

I‘m trying to sign a existing PDF with a certificate that’s located in my local PCs store. Based on [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/.net-framework/beginning-with-digital-signatures-in-.net-framework/) I identified he correct certificate of type [X509Certificate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223098.aspx).

For signing I want to use EvoPdf (unfortnately I can't use iTextSharp here; this would make things easier) and the [demo for signing](http://www.evopdf.com/demo/PDF_Creator/PDF_Security/Digital_Signatures.aspx) uses a [DigitalCertificate](http://www.evopdf.com/help/html_to_pdf/html/T_EvoPdf_DigitalCertificate.htm) which doesn’t provide the information (especially the subject property which is almost totally different in the two classes) I need to identify the correct certificate (I could manually identify the correct certificate from *DigitalCertificatesStore.GetCertificates(CertSystemStore.PersonalCertificates)* but that doesn’t help me much since the certificate might change and I need a robust and lasting solution.
What I did right now is 1st: identify the correct certificate from *X509Store(StoreName.My)* and keep the SerialNumber (of type String) and compare it to the SerialNumber (of type Byte[]) of the *DigitalCertificate* which is the best change to get a match:

```
            foreach (DigitalCertificate cert in DigitalCertificatesStore.GetCertificates(CertSystemStore.PersonalCertificates))
            {
                var serialNumber = String.Empty;
                foreach (var b in cert.SerialNumber)
                {
                    serialNumber = $"{b:X2}{serialNumber}";
                }

                if (serialNumber != x509Cert.SerialNumber)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                this.pdfCertificate = cert;
                break;
            }
```

Anyone got a better solution for this? (How) can I use the x509 cert with EvoPdf directly?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 5/6 I'm using code like this:

```
// Get Personal Certificates with EvoPDF API
var evoCerts = DigitalCertificatesStore.GetCertificates(); 
byte[] evoSerNum = Convert.FromHexString(x509Cert.SerialNumber).Reverse().ToArray();
// Match x509Cert and evoCert by SerialNumber
this.pdfCertificate = evoCerts.GetCertBySerialNumber(evoSerNum);
```